# 'Working' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have created a react app using

`npx create-react-app`

on going to the app directory and then running

`npm start`

it shows the below error

```
npm start

> react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'Working' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'S:\Coding 2\React JS\Abhijet course\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I have tried clearing the npm cache using

`npm cache clean --force`

and also I have tried

`npm audit fix --force`

I have uninstalled the node js and installed it again
then also I am getting the same error

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue on my side :( can you please provide the code in a git repository ?

Comment: I have used basic command to create the react app
`npx create-react-app`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through many article I got to know the reason of this error

If there is **&** in your directory then it will show the above error

so to solve this error firstly remove that **&** from the directory and then again run the below commands to run your react js app on the development server

`npm install`

`npm start`

If it still shows some error then try deleting the **node_modules folder** manually and the delete the **package-lock.json** and after that again run

`npm install`

`npm start`